# Как закрыть дочернее окно при нажатии на кнопку ''Отмена''?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()

    def init_main(self):

        toolbar = tk.Frame(bg='#d7d8e0', bd=2)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fil=tk.Y)

        self.add_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='add.png')
        btn_open_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar,  text='Добавить', command = self.open_dialog, bg='#d7d8e0', bd = 0,
                                    compound = tk.TOP, image = self.add_img)
        btn_open_dialog.pack(side=tk.TOP)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, column=('ID','description','costs','total'), height=15 , show='headings')

        self.tree.column('ID', width=30, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('description', width=300, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('costs', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.column('total',width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.tree.heading('ID', text='№')
        self.tree.heading('description', text='Описание')
        self.tree.heading('costs', text='Сумма')
        self.tree.heading('total',text='Итог')

        self.tree.pack()

    def open_dialog(self):
        Child()


class Child(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_child()

    def init_child(self):

        def destroy_window(root):
            root.destroy()

        self.title('Доходы/Расходы')
        self.geometry('400x220+400+300')

        label_description = tk.Label(self, text='Описание: ')
        label_description.place(x=50, y=50)
        label_select = tk.Label(self, text='Доходы/Расходы: ')
        label_select.place(x=50, y=80)
        label_sum = tk.Label(self, text='Сумма: ')
        label_sum.place(x=50, y=110)


        self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_description.place(x=200,y=50)
        self.entry_money = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_money.place(x=200,y=110)

        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=(u'Доходы',u'Расходы'),state='readonly')
        self.combobox.current(0)
        self.combobox.place(x=200,y=80)

        btn_add = tk.Button(self, text='Добавить')
        btn_add.place(x=220, y=170)
        btn_add.bind('<Button-1>')

        btn_cancel = tk.Button(self, text='Отменить')
        btn_cancel.place(x=300, y=170)
        btn_cancel.bind('<Button-1>')


        self.grab_set()
        self.focus_set()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При инициализации кнопки "Отменить":

```
btn_cancel = tk.Button(self, text='Отменить', command=lambda: self.destroy())
btn_cancel.place(x=300, y=170)
```

или

```
def destroy_window():
    self.destroy()

btn_cancel = tk.Button(self, text='Отменить', command=destroy_window)
btn_cancel.place(x=300, y=170)
```

или

```
def destroy_window(window):
    window.destroy()

btn_cancel = tk.Button(self, text='Отменить', command=lambda window=self: destroy_window(window))
btn_cancel.place(x=300, y=170)
```

Суть во всех случаях будет одна и та же.

Для кнопок лучше не делать привязку к событию `<Button-1>`. Когда я так делал, кнопка оставалась нажатой после отпускания мыши. Лучше делать обработку нажатия кнопки через параметр `command` при создании кнопки. Тем более что у вас `btn_cancel.bind('<Button-1>')` ничего не делает - при привязке обработчика к событию должна указываться функция-обработчик, примерно так:

```
btn_cancel.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.destroy())
```

или

```
def destroy_window(event):
    self.destroy()

btn_cancel.bind('<Button-1>', destroy_window)
```